# I want to compress each letter in a string with a specific length

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following string:
`x = 'aaabbbbbaaaaaacccccbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'`. I want to get an output like this: `abaacbbb`, in which "a" will be compressed with a length of 3 and "b" will be compressed with a length of 5. I used the following function, but it removes all the adjacent duplicates and the output is: `abacb` :

```
def remove_dup(x):
if len(x) < 2:
    return x
if x[0] != x[1]:
    return x[0] + remove_dup(x[1:])
return remove_dup(x[1:])
x = 'aaabbbbbaaaaaacccccbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'

print(remove_dup(x))
```

It would be wonderful if somebody could help me with this.
Thank you!

Comment: Nowhere in your code are the factors of 3 and 5 implemented. Also, why recursion?

Comment: you can try using `reduce` https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#reduce

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a homework question with special constraints, this would be more conveniently and arguably more readably implemented with a regex substitution that replaces desired quantities of specific characters with a single instance of the captured character:

```
import re
def remove_dup(x):
    return re.sub('(a){3}|([bc]){5}', r'\1\2', x)

x = 'aaabbbbbaaaaaacccccbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
print(remove_dup(x))
```

This outputs:

```
abaacbbb
```